# Getting navigation bar height in dependency service - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i have this issue wherein i need to get the navigation bar height in my Dependency Service.

Currently I am stuck on what to follow here. I tried everything i find in stackoverflow and google but no one works for me.

Heres my code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceInfo))]
namespace Wicket.App.Mobile.iOS.Framework
{
    public class DeviceInfo : IDeviceInfo
    {
        public float StatusBarHeight => (float)UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Size.Height;

        public float NavigationBarHeight => GetNavigationBarHeight();

        public static UINavigationController NavigationController { get; set; }

        public float GetNavigationBarHeight()
        {
            //Get navigation bar height


            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I already completed the android part and it works good. The only problem now is in iOS. I have tried getting the instance of navigationcontroller in AppDelegate so that I can just get the bar frame like this `NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
var navheight = GetTopViewController().NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height;


public static UIViewController GetTopViewController()
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;

        if (vc is UINavigationController navController)
            vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();

        return vc;
    }
```

Comment: i already tried that and it crash my app or it resullts to null

Comment: its always result to null on NavigationController part. not i use the dependency on my Page constructor

Comment: How is your Navigation Starts ?

Comment: it started from a master detail page

Comment: Is your MD page is initialized as MainPage= NavigationPage(MD) ? 
Or, Your Details Page in your MD Page are Pushed as Navigation Page?

Comment: my detail page pushed a Content Page. by default content page shows navigation menu when use in a master detail

Comment: still gets null when cast to UINavigationController. it always gets UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

How about pass an instance of viewController as parameter in the function inside the `IDeviceInfo`?

Try this:

```
 public void getNaviHeight(ContentPage vc)
    {
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(vc);
        if (renderer == null)
        {
            renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(vc);
            Platform.SetRenderer(vc, renderer);
        }
        var viewController = renderer.ViewController;

        var h = viewController.NavigationController?.NavigationBar.Frame.Height;

    }
```

And use the dependency:

```
public MainPage ()
{
        DependencyService.Get<IDeviceInfo>().getNaviHeight(this);
}
```

Comment: Did you get the viewController? Can you provide a simple demo or some more codes to show the structure of your project?

Comment: I get a ViewController but the NavigationController is always null

Comment: So, is the viewController you get same as the controller your want? And Is the viewController really have a `NavigationController` in your code?

Comment: Im not sure with the viewcontroller I get is what I want. The page that I get has navigation bar with menu icon/burger icon. So im sure there should be a NavigationController

Comment: Can you check the `viewcontroller`  whether it is the correct one. I think if it is the correct one and after you get it, you should get its `navigationController`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184075/discussion-between-jack-hua-and-secret-coder).

Answer (score 0):

this worked to me:

```
var navigationBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Subviews[0].Subviews.OfType<UINavigationBar>().FirstOrDefault();

if(navigationBar != null)
{
      // continue here...
}
```